# Timer and Navigation in online aptitude test

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am a novice in php web app dev.I am designing an online aptitude test. But i met some problem that i couldnt proceed further. This are

1. The timer restart itself when i click on the navigation for next question
2. When a question is not answered and the next button is clicked, an eror pops out.
   I have poor knowlege of ajax and jquery but belive they can be usedful. Help me in what ever way please to achieve my goal.

below are my codes:

```
//test.php

<?php
session_start();

// th value of q is given as 1 from the start quiz button of the users home page
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
$number = (int)$_GET['q'];
}else{
header('Location : index.php');
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
{

    header("Location: ../login.html");
}
//connection to the db
include_once '../dbconfig.php';

$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE aid=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$qr = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions ");
$qr->execute();

$count = $qr->rowCount();
$qrow=$qr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$qst = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions where quesNo='$number' ");
$qst->execute();
$qstrow=$qst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>

<body>
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><div id="hms">00:05:00</div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
             </header>        
            <div class="item active">


<?php 
//Code to process score(saved is session variable) and move to the next question
                    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
                        $ans=$_POST['ans'];
                        $number=$_POST['number'];
                        $next = $number+1;

                    if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
                            $_SESSION['score'] = '0';
                    }
$qrs = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions ");
$qrs->execute();

$counts = $qrs->rowCount();

$sqlans= "SELECT * FROM answers where quesNo='$number' and right_ans='1'";  
    foreach ($db_con->query($sqlans) as $rowsans) {
        if($ans==$rowsans['ans_id']){
            $_SESSION['score']++;
        }

        if($number==$count){
            header('location:final.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            header('location:test.php?q='.$next);
        }

    }
                }
            ?>
                     <div class="containerx" style="height:530px;">
                <div class="image" style="width:100%">
                     <div class="main">

                            <hl> Question <?php echo $number ?> of <?php echo $count; ?></hl>
                                <div class="test">
                                    <form method="post" action="">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td coLspan=”2”>
                                            <h3>Que <?php echo $qstrow['quesNo']; ?>: <?php echo $qstrow['ques']; ?></h3>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php                       
            $sqla= "SELECT * FROM answers where quesNo='$number'";


                foreach ($db_con->query($sqla) as $rowsa) {
                                 ?>
                            <tr>
                                                <td>
            <input type="radio" name="ans" value=" <?php  echo $rowsa['ans_id']; ?>"/> <?php  echo $rowsa['ans']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>
                     <input type="submit" id="btn_next" name="submit" value="Next Question"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>"/>
                        </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            </table>

                            <!--<div class="caption page-carousel pull-left">-->


                            </div>   

                              <div class="site-full-width darkbluecolor">
                                <div class="container">


              </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

</body>
</html>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function count(){
            var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
            var pieces= startTime.split(":");

            var time = new Date();
            time.setHours(pieces[0]);
           console.log( time.setMinutes(pieces[1]));
            time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);


             console.log( time.setMinutes(pieces[1]));

            var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
            var newTime=timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];

            document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML=newTime;


           if(newTime==="00:00:00"){
                clearTimeout(time_out);
                $('#btn_next').css('display',' none');
                alert("Sorry Your time is over");

            }  
            time_out= setTimeout(count,1000);



        }
        count();

    }); 



    </script>
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get you welll..., What do you mean by posting separate questions... Do you mean i should treat each question value indivdually ?

Comment: I'm talking about your Stack Overflow post, not your code :) You have two distinct problems you're dealing with. I was suggesting that you post them as separate questions with separate [mcve]s

Comment: ok i understand.. Thanks